# Is dplyr:do() generally slower than the specialized functions in dplyr?

Tags: r, performance, dplyr

Suppose I have the following `data.frame`

```
x <- data.frame("a" = rep(1:3, each = 3), 
                 b = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, NA))
```

Now I want to fill the `NA`'s **per group** from above using `fill()`. The simple:

```
x %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  fill(b)
```

wont work as `fill()` apparently doesnt work on a per group basis, unless wrapped in a `do()` command (NA's in group 2 are filled with 1's, although they should be NA). The following is therefore what I want

```
x %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  do(fill(., b))
```

This is certainly a very clean way of doing this, however, I was wondering if `dplyr:do()` is generally expected to be slower than some workaround using the "standard" `dplyr` functions.

For example I could achieve a similar result like this

```
x %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  filter(n() != sum(is.na(b))) %>%
  fill(b)
```

This is not the same since in the second case group's with only `NA`'s column `b` are just filtered prior to using `fill()`, yet I generally wonder if a workaround is even worth considering or is `do()` good enough?

### Update: 15.12.2017

`dplyr::fill()` works now on a per group basis so may "workaround" is not necessary anymore.

Comment: why not try benchmarking it yourself ... ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the original intention, but perhaps the output of `x %>% group_by(a) %>% fill(., b)` (not respecting the grouping and not giving a warning or error) could be a bug (it's still a relatively new tidyr function afaik)

Comment: Yeah, my guess is that `fill` is meant to work per-group, but doesn't yet. `do` is very slow (in my experience) and should be avoided if possible. I would load the zoo library and use `x %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(b = na.locf(b, na.rm=FALSE))` until `fill` accommodates this case.

Comment: When I used `fill()` recently, it worked on a group-by-group basis.